# what is the better way to provide pytest parametrize when partial of parameters are duplicated in all test scenario

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Question about if I should optimize the code as test_prefix_2. I have one testcase required passing different parameter that are changed in some case and some parameters are not changed. Two different ways to write it like  method 1 or method2
However, since parameter state, country are used for this testcase only. Does everyone have preference to write testcase like method2? shortpoint is in that way function parse_para will only use once only

```
import pytest
#method 1
@pytest.fixture
def funcFix(request):
    return
    #do something with request
@pytest.mark.parametrize('funcFix', [dict(name='google', age=7, state='CA', country='US'),
                                     dict(name='apple', age=2, state='CA', country='US'),
                                     dict(name='amazon', age=4, state='CA', country='US'),
                                     dict(name='facebook', age=1, state='CA', country='US'),
                                     dict(name='stackoverflow', age=6, state='CA', country='US'),
                                     dict(name='walmart', age=8, state='CA', country='US'),
                                     dict(name='wholefood', age=5, state='CA', country='US'),
                                     dict(name='target', age=1, state='CA', country='US'),
                                    ], indirect=['funcFix'])
def test_prefix(funcFix):
    #do some test
    pass

#method 2
def parse_para(**kwargs):
    return {**kwargs, **dict(state='CA', country='US')}
@pytest.mark.parametrize('funcFix', [parse_para(name='google', age=7),
                                     parse_para(name='apple', age=2),
                                     parse_para(name='amazon', age=4),
                                     parse_para(name='facebook', age=1),
                                     parse_para(name='stackoverflow', age=6),
                                     parse_para(name='walmart', age=8),
                                     parse_para(name='wholefood', age=5),
                                     parse_para(name='target', age=1),
                                    ], indirect=['funcFix'])
def test_prefix2(funcFix):
    #do some test
    pass
```

Comment: I don't think you will come up with a better solution than introducing the `parse_para` function. I don't see any problem introducing it.

Comment: so my question is actually as programmer it is suggested to create a `parse_para` to wrap parameter? or just using method 1 is fine